# Jumping to Position on page after Dynamic content added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I use ajax to dynamically add content to my site but i want the page to jump to the content has been added but i cant get i to work.

here is the link i am using to add the content and to jump the the position.

```
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('/console/new_message_profile.php', 'message_area');" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 2000);">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an `id` to the dynamically generated element and then

```
$("#idofdynamicelement")[0].scrollIntoView( true );
// O to make sure its the first item if multiple found
// true to indicate the top position
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you let the page scroll to its bottom by using window.scrollTo(0, 2000); I have tried your code on my server,and it worked fine . Can you give more details?